# how to fix Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

why i'm gonna get this error?, how to fix it, i've tried to follow any intro, but it couldn't get fixed.

> Gradle project refresh failed
>   Error:Could not download artifact 'com.android.tools.build:builder:0.12.2:builder.jar': No cached version available for offline mode

my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

thanks for your solution/ideas.

Comment: Please show us your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle`. And check **`Offline Work`** and try again.

Comment: i cannot find the setting options, where can i get it, pardon me, i'm beginner

Comment: Click on File Menu in android studio.

Comment: i've checked Offline Work and tried it again but i don't get anything, can u tell me other way to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->type gradle in search box and click on the result and uncheck the offline work